# Android SeekBar automatically changes size and offsets the "thumb" so nothing lines up correctly

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar, seekbar

So I'm trying to create a custom SeekBar. Before I thought what I wanted would be accomplishable with a ProgressBar so when I had it as a progress bar it worked fine, I was able to change the colors as I needed using custom drawables. The problem arose when I needed to incorporate a "thumb".

Immediately after I changed the ProgressBar to a SeekBar the seekbar "shrinks" and no longer fits the outline. The first images show the seekbar not fitting the dimensions...

[image]
  [image]

This image is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish...
  [image]

You may also notice that the white "gap/thumb" that I have there is not lined up with the correct place (where the colored drawable ends)
I suspect this is related to the unexplained shrinking that is happening?

***Note:*** When I set the padding of the SeekBar to 0 the view snaps back to the correct dimensions but the "thumb" is still offset and I think this is related to the spacing...
[image]

Here is the XML for the SeekBar

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/call_status_progress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/status_waiting_drawable"
                android:thumb="@drawable/seeker"
                android:progress="1"
                android:max="6"
                android:indeterminate="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
 ...
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the XML for the background drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="2px" />
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#D8D8D8"
            android:centerColor="#D8D8D8"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#D8D8D8"
            android:angle="270"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2px" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/status_waiting"
                android:centerColor="@color/status_waiting"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="@color/status_waiting"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after searching for a long time, as normal these obscure errors usually prove to be simple mistakes or overlooked attributes.

For me my solution was setting the attribute 
[android:thumbOffset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setThumbOffset(int))

```
android:thumbOffset="0dp"
```

I hope this solution will help others in the future.